# Compiling git for armhf - encountering "libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by git)"

Tags: git, openssl, arm, cross-compiling, libcrypto

I am trying to get git to run on my armhf BuildRoot based system.  Since git is not in BuildRoot, I went over to my other Debian based armhf system and compiled it from source there with "make prefix=/usr CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static-libgcc" (I want a static binary).  I then made an archive of that binary and the files in /usr/share/git-core, and un-archived that on the armhf BuildRoot based system.

Now when I try and clone a repo. on the target system via https I get this error:

```
git: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by git)
Cloning into 'test_repo'...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

Both my armhf build system and the target seem to have the same version of libcrypto.so (that is 1.0.0), so I can't see what the problem is in terms of versions.  Anyone got any suggestions to get it to work?

Comment: _"...seem to have the same version..."_ doesn't instil a great deal of confidence - surely the very first thing you'd try is running with the _exact_ same libraries you built against (or conversely building against the exact libraries from the target filesystem). Either there _is_ some significant difference between the two copies of libcrypto.so, or there's something up with Git, but those are then two rather different questions.

Comment: `git` will silently fails in its configuration, and then truck-on as if nothing happened. Go back to the beginning. Checkout or unpack `git`. Configure`git` for the build. Then, after configure, manually inspect `config.log` for errors. You will likely find 3 or 4 of them, especially if you enabled HTTPS through cURL.

Comment: @Notlikethat : both the host system and the target have version 1.0.0 of libcrypto.  Host system is a beaglebone and target is a custom system using buildroot.  I wanted to look for other problems before just copying over the beaglebone library to the target.

Comment: ...that's my _point_. They are nominally the same version, but are they _actually_ identical configurations? "I want to attempt to diagnose the cause of the problem by guessing before trying a really quick and simple test that would definitively narrow it down one way or the other" doesn't seem to be the most efficient debugging strategy.

Comment: Here's one that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390833/no-version-information-available

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to have static binary, use `-static` *linker* option, please (that is `LDFLAGS`).
2. "no version information available" is not a big problem in most of the cases, it's just that your `libcrypto` library don't have symbol versioning information available (as in `VERDEF` ELF section).
3. Your real problem is that your git doesn't have `git-remote-https` helper program (which usually is just a symlink to `git-remote-http`) that should be somewhere in the `/usr/lib/git-core/`.
4. But from [what I see](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/master/package/git) there is already a git package for BuildRoot, so your best bet is just to use that.