# Cannot find XCB plugin

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I have cross compiled and deployed Qt 5.11.1 to Raspberry PI 3 using this tutorial: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

So far everything worked, until I got stuck at point 15:

> [on RPi] Run example, that we've built before. At this point it should
>   just work at fullscreen with 60 FPS and mouse, keyboard, and possibly
>   touch support.

My problem is the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./qopenglwidget 
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Przerwane
```

It seems like Rpi doesnt have proper XCB directory. On the other hand it lists available plugins, so the path should be fine?

ldd returns the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ldd qopenglwidget 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ec7f000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76f58000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x769f2000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x765cc000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x7608e000)
    libbrcmGLESv2.so => /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so (0x76069000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76040000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x75ef8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x75e79000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x75e4c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x75d0d000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f6e000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x75c76000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0x75c4f000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng16.so.16 (0x75c15000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x75bf3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x75be0000)
    libbrcmEGL.so => /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so (0x75ba7000)
    libbcm_host.so => /opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so (0x75b80000)
    libvchiq_arm.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvchiq_arm.so (0x75b6a000)
    libvcos.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvcos.so (0x75b50000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x75b39000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x75a31000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so.6 (0x75996000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x75963000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3 (0x758ea000)
```

It looks ok to me. I also tried this with no success: [(Qt 5.4.1) This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405689/qt-5-4-1-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-th#40991619)

Comment: you have compiled for eglfs, not for xcb, so you must launch your application with the following command: `./qopenglwidget  -platform eglfs`

Comment: I think both should work. When run with eglfs parameter, the situation is the same, it just says that it cannot find eglfs instead of xbc.

Comment: then that indicates that you have not installed correctly. :)

Comment: At which point?

Comment: I have installed Qt 5.10.1 in Rpi following that manual in part and I have no problems.

Comment: I am using 5.11.1, can this be a problem? In the past I have installed lower Qt version using it as well.

Comment: could be, when I wanted to compile Qt 5.11 when the first release was released I had compilation problems for the compatibility of some libraries, so far I have not tried again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177174/discussion-between-bremen-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Hello, I have just recreated all steps for QT 5.10.1 and the problem remains the same.

Comment: I had problems compiling Qt 5.10 with the manual that you indicate so combine the procedure of these 2 tutorials. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204529, https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

Comment: But those steps are exactly the same

Comment: not, check the commands well

Comment: Just solved it, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189348/compiling-qt-base-error-libqt5core-so-5-no-version-information-available#33209037