# Qt, no version information available

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, ubuntu-20.04

```
user@term:~/deployment/App$ ldd AppRun 
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
./AppRun: ./AppRun: no version information available (required by ./AppRun)
  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda93f2000)
```

ubuntu 20.04,
Qt Creqtor 4.11.0,
Qt 5.12.8,
qt from repository.
after compilation (linuxdeployqt.appImage /appDir/appName -qmldir=/myDir) this error,
original file, has no errors.
What could be the reason?

linuxdeployqt.appImage inherited from the old version (ubuntu 14.04, qt Creator 4.5.0, qt 5.7.1), he also worked for ubuntu 18 (I don't remember the configuration)

https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/releases gives error: The host system is too new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling Qt-base: error: libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189348/compiling-qt-base-error-libqt5core-so-5-no-version-information-available)

Comment: i`m not sure. I see no errors due to lack of libraries. i think the problem is in .appImage...

Comment: if execute a https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/releases with the parameter -unsupported-bundle-everything, it will work... but it is unsupported

Comment: What do you use `ldd` for? Does your compiler chain include an explicit call to `ldd`?