# How to solve ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available

Tags: linux, ssh, openssl, centos, libcrypto

I am trying to do ssh and got following message:

```
]#ssh
ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by ssh)
ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by ssh)
ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by ssh)
```

Same thing happened with CURL:

```
]#curl
curl: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1)
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Any solution guys?

Output of ldd ssh is as below:

```
]# ldd /usr/bin/ssh
/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/ssh)
/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/ssh)
/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/ssh)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2c5ff000)
        libfipscheck.so.1 => /lib64/libfipscheck.so.1 (0x00007fce80ce2000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fce80ac3000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fce80671000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fce8046e000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fce80258000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fce8003e000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fce7fe07000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fce7fbed000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fce7f9a8000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fce7f6c1000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fce7f495000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fce7f290000)
        libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007fce7ef51000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fce7ebbd000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fce7e9b8000)
        libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007fce7e7b3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000033de000000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fce7e596000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fce7e392000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fce7e187000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fce7df84000)
        libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fce7dd57000)
        libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007fce7db53000)
        libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007fce7d915000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fce7d70c000)
```

Tried to install older version of openssl but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "no version information available" error from linux dynamic linker mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137773/what-does-the-no-version-information-available-error-from-linux-dynamic-linker)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to uninstall openssl completely then try try to install.
It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Get list of openssl rpm list:
rpm -qa | grep openssl

Try to uninstall all package if possible:
rpm -e

Downlaod openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.x86_64.rpm

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26955011/dir/centos_6/com/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.x86_64.rpm.html

Update openssl packages:
rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I got this error `jalal@klein:~$ rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.src.rpm 
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.src.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest): `

Comment: Download rpm from link mentioned in the html above.
ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/vault.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.x86_64.rpm