# "libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version 'OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found " during shell_exec

Tags: php, git, github, ssh, openssl

I'm running into a bit of a weird issue in PHP using shell_exec to run git commands. This is a brand new image of Ubuntu 16.x LTS with only a copy of Lampp installed and the git packages. Within a php script which I intend to webhook to, running `shell_exec('/usr/bin/git pull 2>&1')` prints out the following error.

```
ssh: /opt/lampp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version 'OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by ssh)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`
```

I can pull the repository using `git pull` from the command line and that the user running apache has ownership of all files in the htdocs directory.

`openssl version -a` results in the following:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN
-DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall
-DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM
-DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

Is this an issue with the Lamp 5.6.21, or is this an issue with my setup?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have `openssl` installed from command line

Comment: Type `openssl version -a` on the command line. Is it OpenSSL 1.0.1 or 1.0.2? (It sounds like your remote repo is supplying binaries built against 1.0.1).

Comment: I've added the output of the command, it looks like it is version 1.0.2, is downgrading necessary?

Comment: @Sidriel - you can probably suffice with: (1) download/build OpenSSL 1.0.1. (2) install at `/opt/openssl-1.0.1`. (3) make a script to launch PHP, and use something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/openssl-1.0.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" /opt/lampp/bin/php`.

Answer (score 3):

So you have XAMPP installed into `/opt/lampp` and trying to run native (as in coming from Ubuntu, not XAMPP) git via `shell_exec()`. What is the environment this shell runs in? It's the environment that XAMPP uses with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set `/opt/lampp/lib`, which is absolutely needed for all XAMPP components (because they're built to use these libraries from `/opt/lampp/lib`). Then git inherits this same environment and (although it has perfect openssl library from Ubuntu somewhere in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`) tries to use libraries from `/opt/lampp/lib`, bang.

What you need is just to clear `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable prior to git invocation, like:

```
$oldldpath = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=");
shell_exec('/usr/bin/git pull 2>&1');
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$oldldpath");
```

Comment: In my situation an app was running scripts with /bin/sh and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the application specific lib. Temporarily setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to empty before running my ssh commands did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. found which package has libcrypto.so: `yum provides *libcrypto.so`
2. install openssl-devel: `yum install openssl-devel`
3. update package: `yum update`