# ssh connection with php

Tags: php, linux

i am a newbie to php and linux. i installed xampp and i am trying to build a ssh connection (installed ssh pass and tried the code below).
i got the following error (in /opt/lampp/logs/error_logs):
„/optcd/lampp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found‘(required by ssh)“

when i type in 
openssl version -a
in the command line i get

> OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 built on: reproducible build, date
>   unspecified platform: debian-amd64 compiler: gcc -DDSO_DLFCN
>   -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/lib/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1\""  OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl" ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"

to me this looks like a newer version of OpenSSL is installed. 
how can i fix this problem?

```
<?php
$password = 'password';
$port = 'port';
$user = 'admin';
$host = 'ip-adr';
$command = 'sshpass -p "'
    . $password
    . '" ssh -p '.$port.' '
    . $user. '@'. $host. ' "';
$result = exec($command);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to reinstall openssl packages?

Comment: Yes. And I am getting the same error again.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802196/libcrypto-so-1-0-0-version-openssl-1-0-1-not-found-during-shell-exec