# MySQL library error on different hardware

Tags: mysql, c, runtime-error

I compiled some C code with MySQL stuff (mybin) on a Ubuntu 14.04.

```
root@vm90:~# cat /etc/issue.net
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
```

The code runs fine on my VM, but if I run this code on my hosters web space, I get:

```
./mybin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: no version information available (required by ./mybin)
```

The code still runs fine!

```
geohei@myhoster:~$ cat /etc/issue.net
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
```

Why is that?
What do I have to change in the compiler settings in order to get rid of this message?

Thanks,

Comment: I have no influence on my hosters' installation, hence I read this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137773/what-does-the-no-version-information-available-error-from-linux-dynamic-linker/156387#156387 

and that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks

Would statically linking the libmysqlclient.so.18 be a solution? I tried this following the second link (since I use CODE::BLOCKS), but no joy. Same error!

Comment: Feedback ... I found no other solution that to install Ubuntu 12.04 (OS of my hoster) on a VM and recompile. This made (of course) the above mentioned message disappear. Not very elegant though ...