# Linux executable doesn't work after patchelf

Tags: linux, gcc, elf, nixos

I would like to package a binary file for use with NixOS. For it to work I have to change the interpreter by patchelf to link to one inside the nix store. So far so good. The binary also has shared libraries, but I get a strange error message if I use patchelf's --set-rpath option followed by the : concatenated list of library paths:

```
./result/bin/exe: ./result/bin/exe: no version information available (required by ./result/bin/exe)
./result/bin/exe: ./result/bin/exe: no version information available (required by ./result/bin/exe)
./result/bin/exe: ./result/bin/exe: no version information available (required by ./result/bin/exe)
./result/bin/exe: ./result/bin/exe: no version information available (required by ./result/bin/exe)
./result/bin/exe: ./result/bin/exe: no version information available (required by ./result/bin/exe)
...
./result/bin/exe: relocation error: ./result/bin/exe: symbol , version  not defined in file  with link time reference
```

*(I removed some of the repeating lines)*

I have [found questions asked on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137773/what-does-the-no-version-information-available-error-from-linux-dynamic-linker) regarding the first error, which should not cause any trouble (linked library doesn't contain version information, while the executable defines what version it wants), although what I find strange is that the name of the libraries are missing. The problem is the next line, I found [similar error messages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643532/relocation-error) saying that maybe a different version of gcc could solve the problem, but again, missing library names. The command I use is `patchelf --interpreter "$(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker)" --set-rpath /nix/store/qt-4.8.7/lib:/nix/store/zlib-1.2.11/lib:/nix/store/gcc-6.4.0-lib/lib:/nix/store/libSM-1.2.2/lib:/nix/store/libICE-1.0.9/lib:/nix/store/libX11-1.6.5/lib:/nix/store/libXext-1.3.3/lib:/nix/store/libXt-1.1.5/lib:/nix/store/mesa-17.1.6/lib exe` (with the long hashes removed).

The strange thing is that I can get the program to run by creating a wrapper that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the exact same thing I try to do with patchelf (I still have to change the interpreter but that causes no problem.), but this is not the solution I want.. What should I try to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem. It seems to be happening if you call *strip -g* on the binary on which you ran *patchelf*. In fact, *strip* gives the following warning

> warning: allocated section `.dynsym' not in segment

My binary seems to be working fine if I don't run *strip* on it.

EDIT: The problem seems to be happening only when the new rpath value is longer than the old one.