# /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available

Tags: haskell, ghc, glibc, haskell-stack, ldd

I created a new project with `stack` which made a project with `resolver: lts-16.12`. When running a sample `.hs` file with `stack runghc src/MyExample.hs`, it works fine, but I'm getting these as well before it runs:

```
/home/lpied/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/bin/ghc: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/lpied/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/bin/../haskeline-0.7.5.0/libHShaskeline-0.7.5.0-ghc8.8.4.so)
/home/lpied/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/bin/ghc: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/lpied/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/bin/../ghc-8.8.4/libHSghc-8.8.4-ghc8.8.4.so)
/home/lpied/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/bin/ghc: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/lpied/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/bin/../terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.8.4.so)
```

I've read things such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38851073/3821009) and can confirm the library  in question:

```
$ ll /lib64/libtinfo.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Aug 08 19:47 /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
```

does not have `VERDEF` / `.gnu.version_d`:

```
$ readelf -V /lib64/libtinfo.so.5|grep gnu
Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 245 entries:
Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 1 entries:
```

It looks like the above message is printed [by this](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/elf/dl-version.c#L81):

```
  if (__glibc_unlikely (map->l_info[VERSYMIDX (DT_VERDEF)] == NULL))
    {
      /* The file has no symbol versioning.  I.e., the dependent
     object was linked against another version of this file.  We
     only print a message if verbose output is requested.  */
      if (verbose)
    {
      /* XXX We cannot translate the messages.  */
      _dl_exception_create_format
        (&exception, DSO_FILENAME (map->l_name),
         "no version information available (required by %s)", name);
      goto call_cerror;
    }
      return 0;
    }
```

I tried setting / unsetting various flags from [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), such as `LD_VERBOSE`, `LD_DEBUG`, `LD_WARN`, but none had any effect.

I don't have permissions to install anything in order to fix the library itself. Any idea if / how these messages can be suppressed in lieu of that? Or any alternative non-invasive fixes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the distribution you are using has built ncurses without symbol versioning. I'm guessing that it is something Fedora-derived, so I filed a bug to change that:

- [ncurses: Please enable symbol versioning](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1875587)

In the meantime, you can build ncurses yourself, probably using

```
./configure --prefix=/home/lpied/opt/ncurses --with-versioned-syms
make
make install
```

This does not need root privileges.

And add `/home/lpied/opt/ncurses/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the configuration of your shell.

Comment: `make install` now requires root privilege. Otherwise, it fails on Fedora 36

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, looks like the bug is still unresolved...

Comment: I had to add a flag: `./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/ncurses --with-versioned-syms --with-termlib`
`sudo make`
`sudo make instal`l