# bash: /azureml-envs/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by bash)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, conda, azure-cli

I build a docker image with azure client installed, and every time when I run azure command, this error message shows up. My docker building file is as follows.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04:20220714.v1

ENV AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH /azureml-envs
# Create conda environment
RUN conda create -p $AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH \
    python=3.8 pip=21.3.1 -c anaconda -c conda-forge

# Prepend path to AzureML conda environment
ENV PATH $AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/bin:$PATH

# Install pip dependencies
RUN pip install 'psutil~=5.8.0' \
                'tqdm~=4.62.0' \
                'numpy~=1.21.0' \
                'ipykernel~=6.0' \
                'azureml-core==1.43.0' \
                'azureml-defaults==1.43.0' \
                'azureml-mlflow==1.43.0.post1' \
                'azureml-telemetry==1.43.0'

# This is needed for mpi to locate libpython
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Install AzureML Client
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
RUN az extension add -n ml -y
```

Here is the result when I run `find . -name libtinfo.so.6*`.

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6.2
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6
./opt/miniconda/lib/libtinfo.so.6.3
./opt/miniconda/lib/libtinfo.so.6
./opt/miniconda/pkgs/ncurses-6.3-h7f8727e_2/lib/libtinfo.so.6.3
./opt/miniconda/pkgs/ncurses-6.3-h7f8727e_2/lib/libtinfo.so.6
./azureml-envs/lib/libtinfo.so.6.3
./azureml-envs/lib/libtinfo.so.6
```

I tried `conda install -c conda-forge ncurses` as suggested in [libtinfo.so.6: no version information available message using conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103046/libtinfo-so-6-no-version-information-available-message-using-conda-environment), but it doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks